# Mysterious IP Address

Tags: ip, whois

Often I need to identify IP addresses. I like to execute whois.exe on the command line.  Have not found a site with the whois information for this IP address:

`164.45.207.200`

Also, I was able to get the reverse lookup, but no clear info on the returned information.

`c8.cf.2da9.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com`

Answer (score 4):

For IP addresses you need to use the whois server of the appropriate [Regional Internet Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry).  You can see that I've done so below by adding "-h whois.arin.net" to the (Linux) whois command line. Generally, one starts with ARIN and moves as directed.  In this case, the IP you've identified falls into ARIN's jurisdiction, and is owned by the DoD/DNIC/DISA.  Further probing of that address is... not recommended.

```
$ whois -h whois.arin.net 164.45.207.200

#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#


#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# https://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=164.45.207.200?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2
#

NetRange:       164.45.0.0 - 164.45.255.255
CIDR:           164.45.0.0/16
NetName:        DNIC-RNET-164-045
NetHandle:      NET-164-45-0-0-1
Parent:         NET164 (NET-164-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Assignment
OriginAS:
Organization:   DoD Network Information Center (DNIC)
RegDate:        1992-11-16
Updated:        2012-02-28
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-164-45-0-0-1



OrgName:        DoD Network Information Center
OrgId:          DNIC
Address:        3990 E. Broad Street
City:           Columbus
StateProv:      OH
PostalCode:     43218
Country:        US
RegDate:
Updated:        2011-08-17
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/DNIC


OrgAbuseHandle: REGIS10-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Registration
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-844-347-2457
OrgAbuseEmail:  disa.columbus.ns.mbx.arin-registrations@mail.mil
OrgAbuseRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/REGIS10-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: MIL-HSTMST-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Network DoD
OrgTechPhone:  +1-614-692-6337
OrgTechEmail:  disa.columbus.ns.mbx.hostmaster-dod-nic@mail.mil
OrgTechRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/MIL-HSTMST-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: REGIS10-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Registration
OrgTechPhone:  +1-844-347-2457
OrgTechEmail:  disa.columbus.ns.mbx.arin-registrations@mail.mil
OrgTechRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/REGIS10-ARIN


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#

$
```

Depending on your whois client, it may automatically follow referrals across to other Regional Registries (RIPE, APNIC, etc.) as shown below.  Even if it doesn't, the top bit of information is pretty explicit about where to go for more answers, allowing you to make the second query yourself.

```
$ whois -h whois.arin.net 212.27.48.10

#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#


#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# https://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=212.27.48.10?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2
#

NetRange:       212.0.0.0 - 212.255.255.255
CIDR:           212.0.0.0/8
NetName:        RIPE-NCC-212
NetHandle:      NET-212-0-0-0-1
Parent:          ()
NetType:        Allocated to RIPE NCC
OriginAS:
Organization:   RIPE Network Coordination Centre (RIPE)
RegDate:        1997-11-14
Updated:        2009-03-25
Comment:        These addresses have been further assigned to users in
Comment:        the RIPE NCC region. Contact information can be found in
Comment:        the RIPE database at http://www.ripe.net/whois
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-212-0-0-0-1

ResourceLink:  https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html
ResourceLink:  whois.ripe.net

OrgName:        RIPE Network Coordination Centre
OrgId:          RIPE
Address:        P.O. Box 10096
City:           Amsterdam
StateProv:
PostalCode:     1001EB
Country:        NL
RegDate:
Updated:        2013-07-29
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/RIPE

ReferralServer:  whois://whois.ripe.net
ResourceLink:  https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html

OrgAbuseHandle: ABUSE3850-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Abuse Contact
OrgAbusePhone:  +31205354444
OrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@ripe.net
OrgAbuseRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE3850-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: RNO29-ARIN
OrgTechName:   RIPE NCC Operations
OrgTechPhone:  +31 20 535 4444
OrgTechEmail:  hostmaster@ripe.net
OrgTechRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/RNO29-ARIN


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#



Found a referral to whois.ripe.net.

% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '212.27.48.0 - 212.27.48.255'

% Abuse contact for '212.27.48.0 - 212.27.48.255' is 'abuse@proxad.net'

inetnum:        212.27.48.0 - 212.27.48.255
netname:        FR-PROXAD
descr:          Proxad / Free SAS
descr:          Server internal infrastructure (SLB)
descr:          Bezons, France
country:        FR
admin-c:        ACP23-RIPE
tech-c:         TCP8-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         PROXAD-MNT
created:        2005-09-05T15:24:55Z
last-modified:  2005-09-05T15:24:55Z
source:         RIPE
remarks:        INFRA-AW

role:           Administrative Contact for ProXad
address:        Free SAS / ProXad
address:        8, rue de la Ville L'Eveque
address:        75008 Paris
phone:          +33 1 73 50 20 00
fax-no:         +33 1 73 92 25 69
remarks:        trouble:      Information: http://www.proxad.net/
remarks:        trouble:      Spam/Abuse requests: mailto:abuse@proxad.net
admin-c:        APfP1-RIPE
tech-c:         TPfP1-RIPE
nic-hdl:        ACP23-RIPE
mnt-by:         PROXAD-MNT
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@proxad.net
created:        2002-06-26T12:46:56Z
last-modified:  2013-08-01T12:16:00Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Technical Contact for ProXad
address:        Free SAS / ProXad
address:        8, rue de la Ville L'Eveque
address:        75008 Paris
phone:          +33 1 73 50 20 00
fax-no:         +33 1 73 92 25 69
remarks:        trouble:      Information: http://www.proxad.net/
remarks:        trouble:      Spam/Abuse requests: mailto:abuse@proxad.net
admin-c:        APfP1-RIPE
tech-c:         TPfP1-RIPE
nic-hdl:        TCP8-RIPE
mnt-by:         PROXAD-MNT
created:        2002-06-26T12:29:10Z
last-modified:  2011-06-14T09:03:07Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@proxad.net

% Information related to '212.27.32.0/19AS12322'

route:          212.27.32.0/19
descr:          ProXad network / Free SA
descr:          Paris, France
origin:         AS12322
mnt-by:         PROXAD-MNT
created:        1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
last-modified:  2001-09-22T09:31:43Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.89.2 (HEREFORD)


$
```